# Hide label if there are no parameters set in template. (Parser functions)

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I have an infobox like this

```
{{Infobox
|name   = {{{name}}}
|status = {{{status}}}
|-
|! style="text-align:center; color:white; font-size:1.4em; line-height:1.3em; background:#827f75" colspan="2" {{!}}Contacts
|-
{{#if:{{{Person1|}}}|
{{!}} Person1
{{!}} {{{Person1}}}
|-
{{#if:{{{Person2|}}}|
{{!}} Person2
{{!}} {{{Person2}}}
}}
```

The issue I have is that the label "Contacts" will be visible even if there's no parameter set for "Person1" or "Person2". This is what i've attempted.

```
{{#if:{{{Person1}}} or {{{Person2}}}|
{{!}} style="text-align:center; color:white; font-size:1.4em; line-height:1.3em; background:#827f75" colspan="2" {{!}}Contacts
}}
```

This does however not work for some reason, it always prints out the label as if the statement is always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if` evaluates the true branch if the condition is not empty and vice versa. At the same time `{{{parameter}}}` evaluates to the same string ("{{{parameter}}}") if this parameter wasn't supplied. In order for it to be evaluated to empty string, you need to provide an empty default value: `{{{parameter|}}}`. Also, `or` is neither needed nor helpful here, so the resulting expression should be:

```
{{#if:{{{Person1|}}}{{{Person2|}}}
```

or

```
{{#if:{{{Person1|{{{Person2|}}}}}}
```

For more information, see:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Parser_functions_in_templates